# Should I average the raw components and then solve using the formula, or formula first before averaging?

Tags: mean

Suppose I was trying to find the average BMI of three of my friends.

I have recorded each of their heights and weights (that is, a total of 3 heights, and 3 weights).
Should I:

- average their heights and weights first, then solve for the BMI
- or should I solve each of their BMIs first, and then average these three BMIs?

My bet is on the second option, but I'm not sure if there's an existing general rule about this one. I also can't explain why my bet is on the second option, just purely instinct.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. You have $\text{BMI} =f(h, w). $ What you are asking is whether $f(\bar h, \bar w) $ or $\bar f$ is correct, isn't it? I am failing to see how this is a statistical query. In any case, I would opt for the second too, that is sound and appropriate.

Comment: @User1865345 thanks for providing the symbolic forms. Yes, that's exactly what I was talking about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BMI of an individual is defined; the formula is designed to take account of the fact that weight and height are related within the same individual.

The average BMI of your friends is the average of their individual BMIs. That is, to get their average BMI, you compute each BMI and average those.

The BMI calculated from average weight and average height as if it were an individuals weight and height is a different quantity, with a different distribution and with a different mean. It doesn't represent the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense to me now. :)

Comment: If Glen_b's post answered your query, please make sure you [accept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer by clicking the checkmark present alongside the post.